# MVC php двухэтажная регистрация проблема валидации на второй странице

Tags: php, mvc, form

изучаю php. Знания и практика пару месяцев.
Есть задача, нужно проверить валидацию на второй странице. На первой я проверяю поле "псевдоним" и регион пользователя, проверка проходит успешно и подгружаю второй view, а вот в нем уже не могу понять как сделать валидацию, тк не понимаю как и куда вставить массив для сбора ошибок и что бы его можно было выводить на второй форме. Возможно ошибка в том что я загружаю вторую форму регистрации в один контроллер, хотя я не уверен. Или вообще такое построение шагов не верное. Подскажите пожалуйста как бы сделали вы? Скину только пример контроллера, если нужно будет что то еще, могу скинуть дополнительно, но думаю что дело только в контроллере.

```
<?php

include_once(ROOT . '/models/User.php');

class RegController
{
    public function actionIndex()
    {

        if (isset($_POST['nick']) and isset($_POST['from_city'])) {
            $nick = $_POST['nick'];
            $from_city = $_POST['from_city'];

            $errors = false;

            if (!User::checkNick($nick)) {
                $errors[] = "*Не заполнены обязательные поля!\n";
            }

            if (User::checkNickExist($nick)) {
                $errors[] = "*Такой псевдоним занят!\n";
            }

            if (!User::checkCityExist($from_city)) {
                $errors[] = "*Такого города не существует!\n";
            }

            if ($errors == false) {

                    require_once(ROOT . '/views/users/reg2.php');

                    return true;

            }

        }

        require_once(ROOT . '/views/users/reg.php');

        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: на втором шаге (шаблоне компонента) где '/views/users/reg2.php' собираются другие поля не nick и from_city? Если так и за обработку формы с  '/views/users/reg2.php' отвечает этот же контроллер, также можете сделать как сейчас только if (isset(<другое поле>) and isset(... под имеющимся условие. Страница по факту одна и тажа, просто контроллер разные шаблоны подключает.

Comment: на втором шаге (шаблоне компонента) где '/views/users/reg2.php' собираются ТАКЖЕ поля nick и from_city

Comment: получается что при отправке формы я передаю еще набор переменных вместе с nick и from_city и поэтому вся валидация проходит заново. Мне нужно проверить валидацию на одной форме, потом на другой форме. Может быть проблема в том что я подгружаю второй шаблон, те логичнее по другому организовать две формы?

Comment: В той реализации что есть, нужно просто вам отличать когда идёт обработка одной формы а когда другой, можно в форму например добавить <input type=”hidden” name=”stap” value=”2” /> (в форме /views/users/reg2.php )  а в коде проверять какой сейчас шаг.

Comment: Как я понял нужно после нескольких шагов зарегистрировать пользователя, можно записывать в сессию номер шага и сохранённые данные при этом, а на последнем шаге уже всё сохранять в БД (при этом в контроллере смотреть какой сейчас шаг и работать с данными как хотите). Ещё подобное можно сделать js, всё на js а в конце все данные разом отправить ajax в php скрипт.

Comment: Все сделал, задача была достаточно тривиальная сводилась к передаче переменной между формами. Сделал передачу nick и from_city через Куку и подставил данные в новую форму, ну а там уже другой контроллер по схожей аналогии будет валидировать и записывать данные. Благодарю что откликнулись, навели на решение.

Comment: у меня будет похожая задача, как раз прикинул себе варианты). Ну через куку, по моему не очень хорошо, их можно подсмотреть и сделать пост запрос на урл (хотя это может ничего не даст злоумышленнику). Если логически, например будет больше 2х шагов, и после каждого шага перебрасывать данные дальше на следующую форму, на последнем шаге будут просто все заполненные поля, как если бы была одна форма. По мне это лишняя логика на беке, т.е. можно js показывать скрывать нужные поля, валидировать js, а на последнем шаге отправить всё разом (вмести с капчей), так на беки будет код проще для понимания.

Comment: Согласен) но у меня задача именно такая, переделывать нельзя)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все сделал, задача была достаточно тривиальная сводилась к передаче переменной между формами. Сделал передачу nick и from_city через Куку и подставил данные в новую форму, ну а там уже другой контроллер по схожей аналогии будет валидировать и записывать данные. Благодарю что откликнулись, навели на решение.